# Check if a value is in one of the several columns in the subquery in CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table1 with three columns (`first_value`, `second_value`, and `third_value`). I need to make a query with `CASE` where it checks if a value (say, 1), can be found in one of those three columns.

Something like this (which won't work):

```
WHEN 1 in (SELECT first_value, second_value, third_value FROM table1) THEN ...
```

I get the error description

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I guess I should use `EXISTS` but I don't understand it.

Comment: Why not `IN ( first_value, second_value, third_value)`?

Comment: Note that `IN` is basically an `OR`, and can be inefficient, especially when used over multiple columns. You may find a `UNION` query to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the suggestion in the comments might have done the trick for you, since you just have the one table.

But just to show how you'd use exists in a more general case:

`select 1` is just a convention, it's a dummy. All exists cares about is whether the result is non-empty. So `select 'taco salad'` works just the same.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/bAKHv6ir

```
create table base_table (
  search_value integer
  );

create table some_values (
  first_value integer,
  second_value integer,
  third_value integer
  );

insert into base_table values
  (1),
  (9),
  (11),
  (20);

insert into some_values values 
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5,6),
  (7,8,9);

select * 
  from base_table bt
 where exists
         (
           select 1
             from some_values sv
            where bt.search_value in (sv.first_value, sv.second_value, sv.third_value)
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can JOIN to the table:

```
...
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON 1 IN (t1.first_value, t1.second_value, t1.third_value)
```

This has the advantage of also making other columns in the table available for the `SELECT` list, if needed, but the risk of duplicating rows if several rows could match.